# How to create gpg key without passphrase?

Tags: qemu, gpg

I have debain 11 ARM64 in qemu and want to generate PGP key.
The following command

```
gpg --passphrase '' --full-generate-key
```

Doesn't work : gpg asking for passphrase over and over again. I need to generate key with following attributes:

1. default algorithm (RSA)
2. default key length (3072)
3. Firstname Lastname
4. e-mail
5. empty comment

How to do that? Please tell me?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1360324/gpg-remove-passphrase